# Draggable element without JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, draggable

I am trying to make a draggable library sort of thing for one of my projects, but I am struggling a bit with making elements draggable. When the element touches the top of the container it starts to rebound the more you move your mouse up, it also randomly gets stuck. Anyone got any ideas why it's doing this, I even put in checks to try prevent it.

```
    SetDragHandlers: function(Obj,ObjIsHandler,Container) /* If the object is the handler, then its parent is the thing that will be moved */
    {
        var ToMove = (!ObjIsHandler ? Obj : Obj.parentNode),
            HandleStyles,
            ObjStyles,
            ContainerStyles,
            ObjLeft,
            ObjTop,
            ObjWidth,
            ObjHeight,
            HandleWidth,
            HandleHeight,
            ContainerWidth,
            ContainerHeight,
            MouseX,
            MouseY;

        var MoveListener = function(e)
        {
            var MouseX_New = Dragger.MouseX(e),
                MouseY_New = Dragger.MouseY(e),
                MouseX_Diff = (MouseX > MouseX_New ? MouseX - MouseX_New : MouseX_New - MouseX),
                MouseY_Diff = (MouseY > MouseY_New ? MouseY - MouseY_New : MouseY_New - MouseY),
                ObjTop_New = ObjTop + MouseY_Diff,
                ObjLeft_New = ObjTop + MouseX_Diff;
            Dragger.log(MouseX_New);
            if
            (
                ObjTop_New + ObjHeight > ContainerHeight || ObjTop < 0
                ||
                ObjLeft_New + ObjWidth > ContainerWidth || ObjLeft < 0
                ||
                MouseX < 0 || MouseY < 0 || MouseX > window.innerWidth || MouseY > window.innerHeight
            ) /* Would go out of bounds */
                return;

            if(ToMove.style.top == '' || ToMove.style.top == null)
                ToMove.setAttribute('style',ToMove.getAttribute('style') + 'top:' + ObjTop_New + 'px;' + 'left:' + ObjLeft_New + 'px;');
            else
            {
                ToMove.style.top = ObjTop_New + 'px'; /* Some px are taken away so the cursor will throw mouseup when the mouse is up. Without this the cursor would be too far to the left or too far up and now throw it */
                ToMove.style.left = ObjLeft_New + 'px';
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        };

        Dragger.AddEventListener(Obj,'mousedown',function(e){
            if(e.which != 1) /* Left mouse button not down */
                return;
            /* Redefine the vars incase they have changed */
            HandleStyles = Dragger.GetFinalStyles(Obj);
            ObjStyles = Dragger.GetFinalStyles(ToMove);
            ContainerStyles = (Container == null || Container == undefined
                                ?
                                    {
                                        height: window.innerHeight + 'px', /* This is done so that less checks need to be done further on. This makes an object we can get the containers width and height from */
                                        width: window.innerWidth + 'px'
                                    }
                                :
                                    Dragger.GetFinalStyles(Container) /* This is generated fresh every time so the container can be resized without trouble */
                              );
            /* The object that will be moving */
            ObjLeft = ObjStyles.left.replace('px','');
            ObjTop = ObjStyles.top.replace('px','');
            ObjWidth = ObjStyles.width.replace('px','');
            ObjHeight = ObjStyles.height.replace('px','');

            /* The object the user has clicked and dragged to move it */
            HandleWidth = HandleStyles.width.replace('px','');
            HandleHeight = HandleStyles.height.replace('px','');

            /* The container the object will move about inside */
            ContainerWidth = ContainerStyles.width.replace('px','');
            ContainerHeight = ContainerStyles.height.replace('px','');

            /* The mouse position */
            MouseX = Dragger.MouseX(e);
            MouseY = Dragger.MouseY(e);

            Dragger.AddEventListener(document,'mousemove',MoveListener);
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        Dragger.AddEventListener(Obj,'mouseup',function(e){
            if(e.which != 1) /* Left mouse button not down */
                    return;
            Dragger.RemoveEventListener(document,'mousemove',MoveListener)
        })
    }
```

Comment: Leading caps. That's usually a convention for naming constructors, it's confusing... See how everything is highlighted in blue?

Comment: Because I use capital letters to show the separation between different words then if I don't use caps on one of the letters it really annoys me.

Comment: You can write code your way but people will have to find out that All Those Variables Aren't Classes because even the syntax highlighting tells us that's meant to be a class. Conventions: `CONSTANT, myVariable, MyClass`.

Comment: Sorry, I'll keep that in mind for future projects.

Comment: How about a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/twCFE/ Sorry It's all in the HTML box, every time I tried to separate it everything broke.